# Mapping between Vim syntax highlighting and Emacs font-lock

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I try to harmonize the colors of my Vim and Emacs. But I am not sure how to map some Emacs faces to Vim. Emacs distinguishes between `keyword` and `builtin`. In shell mode `if` and `case` are of the type `keyword`, but `alias` is a `builtin`. I try to find the equivalent types. In Emacs I can use the function describe-face to inspect the faces in a buffer. How to do the same in Vim? All I found so far is the following list:
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim

This is the list. Some are easy, because they have the same name. But some are not obvious.

```
Emacs                       Vim
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
font-lock-builtin-face      ?
font-lock-comment-face      Comment
font-lock-constant-face     Constant
font-lock-function-face     Function
font-lock-keyword-face      Statement
font-lock-string-face       String
font-lock-type-face         Type
font-lock-variable-face     Identifier
sh-quoted-exec              ?
```

Questions:

1. What is the match for `builtin` and `sh-quoted-exec`?
2. What is the Vim name for the color of sub shells? `$()`
3. What is the Vim name for punctuation? `.;[]`
4. What is the difference in Vim between the option in `shopt -s` and `[ -f`? They do not have the same color.

Comment: If you’re hoping to syntax highlight sh code, be warned, it’s not as robust as you think

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of [Interactively check given string highlight group](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16110/1841)

Comment: (I’m looking for a QA i saw months ago about sh syntax hl and -options.)

Comment: @statox `:hi` shows all faces. How to get the name of the face at the current cursor position?

Comment: With `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")` as the answer to the question I linked says?

Comment: @statox Thanks. I did not understand the question. So i did not realize, what the answer answers.

Comment: No problem :) Can I close your question as duplicate or do you need more information?

Comment: @statox Yes I think so.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following function to my `emacs.vim`:

```
" Inspect Emacs colors with:
" M-x describe-face
" Inspect Vim colors with:
function DescribeFace()
  let l:s = synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1)
  let l:r = synIDattr(l:s, 'name')
  while 1
    let l:st = synIDtrans(l:s)
    if l:s == l:st
      break
    endif
    let l:r .= ' ▷ ' . synIDattr(l:st, 'name')
    let l:s = l:st
  endwhile
  echo l:r
endfunction
command DescribeFace call DescribeFace()
```

The function displays the name of the syntax at the current point and all ancestors.

BTW: this was very useful: https://devhints.io/vimscript